# How to send functional email from Ubuntu using bash and mailutils?

Tags: bash, email, gmail, mail-server, mailutils

I'm trying to set up my first mail server and am encountering issues verifying it is working correctly.

I have 'mailutils' installed and send mail by using:

```
mail username@gmail.com
```

I then enter the subject and body text, and enter `Ctrl-D` to send the email. The issue I then have, is that the mail is not received at my gmail address, and no sign of an error sending is shown in my bash terminal.

I also have an issue sending mail *to* my server. From my gmail account, I try to send an email to `user@mydomain.com` as usual, but after sending, gmail reports the error:

```
The response from the remote server was:

550 Administrative prohibition
```

The issue with sending mail *to* my gmail account I'm tempted to think is because of spam filtering. If so:

- Could anyone suggest a method, still using mailutils, that could circumvent this ?

In sending mail from my gmail account *to* my personal domain, the fact the gmail error mentions a response from 'the remote server' makes me think that the mail is reaching my personal domain. From this I then think, on my remote server, there is something preventing the mail getting through. So:

- Could anyone suggest what could be preventing the mail reaching the remote server from gmail ?

Any assistance with the above questions, along with an explanation, or indications of where I might be misunderstanding something, would be appreciated.

Any auxiliary recommendations, helping to set up my remote mail server, would also be welcomed.

### Port 25 query

The result of running

```
telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
```

Is:

```
Connected to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP l7-longStringHere - gsmtp
```

Comment: What Internet or Cloud provider are you using for your Ubuntu machine that you are trying to send and receive mail? Most ISP or Cloud provider will block TCP port 25. So, please [edit] your question and add the output of `telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25`.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question.

Comment: You are possibly missing SPF records and many, many (did I say enough "many") other things. I have created I very rudimentary guide at https://www.kadifeli.com/fedon/hint.php?cloud_mailconf . Some aspects are _postfix_ and _dovecot_ related. But, I think it is worth looking at.